# Firebase Functions Node JS: Cannot find module './auth/credential'

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

After updating to the latest dependencies my Firebase Functions backend won't run in either `firebase emulators:start` or `firebase functions:shell`. It fails with the following exception

```
- C:\Users\yannk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:23:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[runtime-status] [23304] Error in handleMessage: {\"frb\":{\"cwd\":\"C:\\\\Project\\\\projdir\\\\firebase\\\\functions\",\"projectId\":\"snapdiscover-luminarcom\",\"triggerId\":\"\",\"emulators\":{\"firestore\":{\"name\":\"firestore\",\"host\":\"192.168.112.113\",\"port\":8080,\"pid\":23900},\"auth\":{\"name\":\"auth\",\"host\":\"192.168.112.113\",\"port\":9099}},\"adminSdkConfig\":{\"databaseURL\":\"https://snapdiscover-luminarcom.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"snapdiscover-luminarcom.appspot.com\"},\"socketPath\":\"\\\\\\\\?\\\\pipe\\\\C:\\\\Project\\\\projdir\\\\firebase\\\\functions\\\\23304\"},\"opts\":{\"nodeBinary\":\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\",\"env\":{}}} => Error: Cannot find module './auth/credential'\nRequire stack:\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\firebase-namespace.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\default-namespace.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\index.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\apps.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\providers\\database.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js\n- C:\\Users\\yannk\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js: Error: Cannot find module './auth/credential'\nRequire stack:\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\firebase-namespace.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\default-namespace.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\index.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\apps.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\providers\\database.js\n- C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js\n- C:\\Users\\yannk\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\firebase-namespace.js:23:20)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)"}}
[warn] !  functions: Cannot find module './auth/credential'
Require stack:
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\default-namespace.js
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\index.js
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\apps.js
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\providers\database.js
- C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\index.js
```

I have tried

- Update everything to the latest dependencies (using `ncu -u`)
- Assured that admin.initializeApp() is called

index.ts

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'


admin.initializeApp()

[...]
```

I've also tried to initialize the app explicitly

index.ts

```js
import { ServiceAccount, initializeApp, credential } from 'firebase-admin' 
import * as serviceAccount from './api-key.json'


initializeApp({
    credential: credential.cert(<ServiceAccount>{
        projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
        clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
        privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key
    })
})
[...]
```

Both give the same error. I need to test my code before deploying it to the backend.
Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks

**Edit:** Now I get a new error:

```
[warn] !  TypeError: util.assign is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\qs\lib\formats.js:13:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\projdir\firebase\functions\node_modules\qs\lib\utils.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"TypeError: util.assign is not a function\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\formats.js:13:23)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Project\\projdir\\firebase\\functions\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\utils.js:3:15)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)"}}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "capitalize-sentence": "^0.1.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.8.0",
    "perspective-api-client": "^3.1.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "mocha": "^8.3.2",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Somewhere you still have a fairly old version of `firebase-admin` installed in your system. The module `./auth/credential` was present in versions 9.1.0 and before.

Comment: Thanks, I have made sure all dependencies are using the latest version using `npm install <dependency>@latest`, so that: "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.8.0" . Now I get a new error: `util.assign` is not a function. (I have updated my question accordingly)